# Eclipse plugins for Seam Development

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, seam

i just wanna ask what plugins for Eclips etc people use when they develop a Seam Application.

The once we use are:

- JRebel (Couldn't live without it, extreamly nice)
- Subclips
- M2
- JAutoDoc
- JbossTools

//Trind

Comment: Don't they have their own distribution of eclipse - jBoss tools or something?

Comment: Well it is Eclipse with JbossTools and some logo when you start it:P and you get support for it as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've used "plain" Eclipse with the JBossTools plugin, and I've also used JBoss Developer Studio. Pretty much the same experience either way.